# RestKit saveToPersistentStore calls controllerDidChangeContent before data is written to the database

Tags: core-data, ios7, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have RestKit 0.23.0 with Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController in my project. I want to change an attribute of an entity and reload my view in `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller`.

I get the managed object that I want to change from `objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext`, change the attribute and call `objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]`. The `controllerDidChangeContent`method is called, but the data is not written to the database at that time.

After debugging in `NSManagedObjectContext+RKAdditions.m`, I saw that `success = [contextToSave save:&localError];`is called two times. The first run fires `controllerDidChangeContent` (data is not written to the database at that time) and the second call writes the data to the database, but does not call `controllerDidChangeContent`.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Just test again without calling save. Who knows what RestKit is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I do not call `saveToPersistentStore`, I cannot see the changes with `performFetch` in my `NSFetchedResultsController`. Maybe here is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing 'wrong', you are just seeing 2 different stores being saved. First the main thread store (non-persistent) and then the persistent store (backed on disk). The main thread store is a child of the persistent store.

So, you get a notification when the main thread store is saved, because that is what you asked for, but the persistent store hasn't been saved yet so nothing has been saved to disk.

This should not cause you a problem. If it does you either have a logical error in your code or your approach to solving the problem isn't quite right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You pointed me in the right direction. I think, it's more a Core Data thing. I asked a new question with a description of what I want to accomplish. Would be nice if you have a look here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914904/nsfetchedresultscontroller-notify-for-changes-in-another-entity-best-practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914904/nsfetchedresultscontroller-notify-for-changes-in-another-entity-best-practice)