# NSFetchedResultsController notify for changes in another entity (Best practice)

Tags: core-data, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities (MetaData and Prices) with a many-to-many relationship. The entity MetaData has an attribute `dataIsInvalid` to invalidate all related prices in the entity `Price`. I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` for `MetaData` and one FRC for `Price`.

The predicate for FRC `Price` is `@"ANY metaData.dataIsInvalid == 0"`. Of course, if I change the `dataIsInvalid` attribute in `MetaData`, the `controllerDidChangeContent` method from FRC `Price` is not called, but the method in FRC `MetaData`. So I want to reload the FRC `Price` data in the `controllerDidChangeContent` method from FRC `MetaData`.

The problem is, that the FRC `Price` cannot see the changes in `MetaData` at that time. So that doesn't work.

What is the best practice for this scenario? Should I use `NSNotificationCenter`with `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`? This will be called after `saveToPersistentStore` and the FRC `Price` can see the changes.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: What else does metadata contain? Just the flag?

Comment: `MetaData` contains a lot more data about the related entries in the `Price` entity. E.g. total count of prices, server response timestamp, position, the request timestamp and so on.

Comment: Consider implementing a custom setter on `MetaData` which updates `dataIsInvalid` and also 'dirties' all of the related `Price`s so that they are notified as having changed (even though you didn't actually change anything).

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But there are about 16 entities in relationship with MetaData. If there is no other way, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can send notifications on a controller level instead of the core data level. If you ever do something to change metadata, have the controller that handles that notify the controller that has the FRC for Price after the save completes, to do a performFetch.

Comment: I'm still struggling when I have to save the context. I put a new question and a project on Github. It would be nice, if you have time to have a look at it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998760/core-data-with-many-to-many-relationship-changes-in-first-entity-not-visible-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998760/core-data-with-many-to-many-relationship-changes-in-first-entity-not-visible-in).